# What's the js equivalent of RailsInstaller?

Tags: javascript

I want to build a small js plugin, and I want to try that with ReactJS.

ReactJS recommends installing using *npm* and *browserify*.

In my experience with *Ruby on Rails*, there are always a lot of things to install, and using Windows introduces additional problems.

With *Ruby* it is *Rails Installer*. What is JS equivalent of Rails Installer? i.e. a tool that lets me install all necessary packages with one step?

I did a little bit of search, find that I need to install:

1. NodeJS, NPM
2. NVM
3. Webpack or Browerify
4. Babel

I think there may be others that I need.

Answer (score 0):

To start the project you need `node` and `npm` because `webpack`, `browserify` and `babel` is npm packages.

The only way to install all packages in one step is to install package that actually depend on all packages you need. There is a lot of ReactJS starter kits in github like this https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit

I, personally recommend you doing such a things by yourself - its not a big deal if you understand what you want. In the root of all nodejs projects there is a file `package.json` every time you need a new module (package) just type `npm install -S <module_name>` in the root directory of your project.

This new module appears in `node_modules` directory and because of `-S` flag it name also will be stored in dependencies of your project in `package.json` file so that in the future you can just type `npm install` to install all dependencies (aka modules/packages) of your project.